# "Naḥat Ruaḥ LeYoẓro" source

Tags: sources-mekorot, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, prayer-book, quotations

At the end of מוסף לשבת in [דרכי אבות השלם](http://www.kodeshbook.co.il/product.asp?productid=4540) (p. 375), a quotation is written in the name of רבי יהודה:

> אמר רבי יהודה: אשרי מי שעמלו בתורה ועושה נחת רוח ליוצרו

Can anyone help me find the exact source for this quotation? I've found [Berakhot 17a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=17&format=text) in the name of רב יוחנן with almost the exact same text:

> ר' יוחנן כי הוה מסיים ספרא דאיוב אמר הכי סוף אדם למות וסוף בהמה לשחיטה והכל למיתה הם עומדים **אשרי מי שגדל בתורה ועמלו בתורה ועושה נחת רוח ליוצרו**

But, I have not found any quotation with that wording in the name of רבי יהודה.

Comment: There seems to be a dispute as to whether it is Rabbi Yochanan or Rabbi Yehuda who said this.

Comment: [Here](http://www.bet-refael.com/show_art.php?artID=18) and [here](http://haretzion.org/component/content/article/14/140-hesped-ariel-ness) cite a version of that gemara in the name of R' Yehuda. Incidentally, see the end of אותיות דרבי עקיבא, which [quotes this teaching](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32566&st=&pgnum=74) as that of R' Yitzchak in the name of R' Abba.

Comment: Closely related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30613

Comment: @Fred I too found the Yeshivat Har Etzion link on Google, but decided not to include it in my post for two reasons: A) they quote it in the name of the Mishnah and the only source for this saying I've found is in the Gemara and B) because they don't offer a source for the quotation.

Comment: Wow, thank you @DoubleAA! If I understand this Rav correctly, he is simply stating "ולא מופיע בתלמוד" (!) that this quotation does not have a source in the Talmud??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rav Meir Mazuz [writes](http://www.ykr.org.il/modules/Ask/answer/2984) that the source is unknown.

It seems that this is based on an version that we no longer have.

The [Noda Biyehuda](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_20551_78.pdf) quoted it, too.